# The dl tag is shown in different browsers differently why?

Tags: html, css

Why is the `<dl>` tag that is included in the triplet of `<dl>, <dt>, <dd>` elements intended for creating the definition list is shown differently in different browsers and how to fix it?

> Example: If you are looking at this code with  Chrome browser, then everything
>   will be fine (if you are a Chrome Developer) and you don't see any unusual, but if you look at Mozilla (if you are a Web developer) (the developer
>   edition in my situtation), then you will see the fantastic indentation
>   that which comes out from nowhere.

Here's a [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x1vbmtmb/2/) look in the `mozilla` and you will see the difference.

```css
.horizontal_dl {
  /*white-space: nowrap;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.horizontal_dl dd {
    margin-left: 155px;
    display: flex;
    line-height: 19px;
}
.horizontal_dl dt {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 0px;
  
}
dl, dt {
  color: #000;
  font-size: .9em;
}
dl {
  margin-top: 0;
}
dt {
  font-weight: 700;
}
dd {
  margin: 0 0 .563em;
}
.text_upper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
 <dl class="horizontal_dl">
   <dt class="text_upper">Full Name</dt>
   <dd>Robert Smith</dd>
   <dt class="text_upper">D.o.b.</dt>
   <dd>05 June 1988</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I didn't see any differences in Chrome and Firefox, looked the same to me.

I think the following code might help you to get the results you want.
I only rebased the dd, dl and dt part of your code, but it hopefully helps you to get back on the right track.

It looks something like this:

```css
dl {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
dl dt {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
    color: #000;
  font-size: .9em;
}
dl dd {
  flex:0 0 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

dl {
  margin-top: 0;
}
dt {
  font-weight: 700;
}
dd {
  margin: 0 0 .563em;
}
.text_upper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
 <dl class="horizontal_dl">
   <dt class="text_upper">Full Name</dt>
   <dd>Robert Smith</dd>
   <dt class="text_upper">D.o.b.</dt>
   <dd>05 June 1988</dd>
</dl>
```

You might want to paste this in your jsfiddle, at my side I can see inline markup.

Comment: thank you but in Mozilla it looks difference  @TheAmplifier

Comment: your'e part of code isn't worked.I have the same issue @TheAmplifier

Comment: Firefox Developer is my default browser, I indeed see the jump in your flexbox container. But that jump also shows in my Chrome and Safari browser.

Comment: I added a snippet that might clear things up for you

Comment: glad I could help!